# Trying to get SASS working with Netbeans 7.4

Tags: ruby, netbeans, compass-sass

I am working on a project which has a number of `sass` files located in a sub directory called `sass`.  I understand that in order for these files to be generated into `css` I am required to install `ruby` and `compass`.

I've done this. I am on a Windows 7 64bit OS. I downloaded the Ruby .exe from their site and ran it. I ran `sass -v` to check the version that was installed and it was `Sass 3.4.1`

Next I went into `Netbeans` and went tools->options->miscellaneous and went to the `CSS Preprocessors` tab. From here I entered the `path` to my `sass.bat` file which was was follows:

> C:\Ruby193\bin\sass.bat

Following this I then restarted `netbeans` and opened a command line. I navigated to the `sass` folder of my project and ran the command `compass watch` however when I make a change to the `sass` file and save it is not being detected by `compass` which makes me think I've done something wrong.

I'd appreciate any help with this. I've not got a lot of experience with SASS.

Comment: Just a guess - have you configured the (ruby) config.rb, e.g. the values for http_path and sass_dir ? And does the build works and it's only not working for watch?

Comment: Actually looking in the folder there is not `config.rb` file, I'm wondering did the Designer forget to commit that file, in which case it would explain a lot as to why it isn't working!

Comment: Another guess - I'd think there is a config.rb file, but maybe you're not looking at the right location? It should be directly in your project folder.